# Dimension of sumset vs sum of dimensions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, dimension-theory

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$. Is it true that
$$
\dim(A+A)\le 2\dim A
$$

for some dimensions – say, lower box for the LHS and upper box for the RHS.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3855342/the-hausdorff-dimension-for-sum-of-sets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A+A$ is a Lipschitz image of the set $A\times A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ under the map $(x,y)\to x+y$. If $A$ is covered by $N$ balls of radius $\varepsilon$, then $A\times A$ is covered by $N^2$ balls of radius, say, $\sqrt{2}\varepsilon$, thus the box dimension (lower or upper) of $A\times A$ does not exceed twice that of $A$, and the Lipschitz map does not increase the dimension.

Comment: This seems to contradict the answer to the linked question.

Comment: @ChristianRemling why? It is about other dimension